# Product Page not working in Magento PWA venia theme local setup?

Tags: magento2, progressive-web-apps, magento2.4

I successfully installed venia on my local system. I connected the backend URL with Magento 2.4.4, Homepage and list page working fine. But, the Product page is not working. When I click on the product page it shows like the below image. Any solution to resolve this issue? Please let me know if any.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Run this command : `yarn run buildpack create-custom-origin ./` and restart your project.

Comment: tried but same issue.. Also in the network tab - it gives this error for product details query - Field \"description\" of type \"String\" must not have a sub selection."

Answer (score 0):

try "yarn run build" or "npm run build" then "yarn/npm start"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is turn on developer mode; command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Then, after that, check the debug log
path of error log:

```
magento root dir/var/log/debug.log
```

If there is any error show to you then we will be able to help you till we don't know the error and can't give any solution.

Comment: this might be better as a comment, instead of an answer? By saying you can't help until they do this, you can't actually provide a concrete answer to this question.

Comment: Sorry, my friend I don't have so many reputation that I can comment, so I tried my best to convey my point through answer method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below answer
php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_EavGraphQlAux Magento_CatalogGraphQlAux Magento_PageBuilderPwa Magento_ReCaptchaGraphQlPwa Magento_ReCaptchaPwa Magento_SalesGraphQlAux Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQlPwa Magento_WeeeGraphQlAux